# date_format timezone strangeness

Tags: r, timezone

I defined a date with a timezone, but when I print it out using the `scales` package `date_format` it gives me the time in UTC, which is awkward for my purpose.

```
> library(scales)
> st <- as.POSIXct("2015-10-31 00:00:00",tz="US/Pacific")
> st
[1] "2015-10-31 PDT"
> fmt <- date_format("%Y-%m-%d %R %Z")
> fmt(st)
[1] "2015-10-31 07:00 UTC"
```

Interestingly this works (so `POSIXct` seems to understand the timezone) - but does not give me enough control over the format:

```
> format(st,usetz=T)
[1] "2015-10-31 PDT"
```

This unreliability is hinted at in the help for `?date_format`:

> When %z or %Z is used for output with an object with an assigned time
>   zone an attempt is made to use the values for that time zone — but it
>   is not guaranteed to succeed.

So my question is, how do I *make* it succeed?

Suggesting workarounds is fine and may attact upvotes, but please understand the point of this question is that I want to obtain insight as to what is going on with `date_format`.

Comment: You should *avoid* three-letter timezone acronyms as they are *not* standardized. PDT may mean different things to different locales. The *strange* thing is that `st` returned `PDT` instead of eg `.... 00:00:00 + 07:00Z`. R's localization isn't very consistent - in this case `st` used a custom format that. If you want to display dates in a *specific* format, define it explicitly in your format string. In this case, what is the exact format you want to return?

Comment: Avoid the three-letter timezones? I didn't use them, `date_format` and `format` did. As the example shows.

Comment: What is the format you want to return?

Comment: Depending on what I am doing, I want different things, but I always want it to use the timezone I entered it with. But you can assume I want the format I used in the example if you need something concrete to work with.

Comment: Where is `date_format` defined? It's not a base function. Why don't you use `format`?

Comment: Interesting. Hadn't noticed that. Is is in `scales`.

Comment: Why do you believe `format.POSIXct` doesn't give you enough control?

Comment: The help does not indicate that format.POSIXct has format control, so I assume that it did not. But it does I see. So this is looking like a `date_format` bug in `scales`?

Comment: You seem to have a different documentation than standard R: `help("format.POSIXct")`

Comment: Yeah, ok, I looked in ?format.

Comment: which provides a link to the `POSIXct` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of `date_format` is very short:

```
function (format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "UTC") 
{
    function(x) format(x, format, tz = tz)
}
```

It should be obvious why the timezone is changed if you don't change the default.

Comment: Ok, should have found this myself. Still confusing.

Comment: scales mainly contains convenience functions for plotting (in particular to be used in ggplot2).

Comment: Not sure why `date_format` overrides the timezone. Seems to negate some of its convenience then.